# set message persistence in rabbitmq.xml file in spring

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp

I have used RabbitMQ with Java SE before. Now I use RabbitMQ with Spring with help of Spring and RabbitMQ documentation. Now I have a problem.

Can any one tell me how can set **MessageProperties** in rabbitmq-context .xml file?

I want to set message properties to persistence. How can do it?

Comment: Message properties are set on creation of each message.  I am not sure that you are asking the right question, what is the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend` the framework provides `MessageProperties` object for the `Message` with `PERSISTENT` `deliveryMode` as default value. You can provide some custom `MessageConverter` to the `RabbitTemplate` instance which sets some other `deliveryMode`.

It isn't a part of configuration, but per message, so you can achieve that only manually from the code.